# ROS Answers SE migration: Create octree

Tags: ros, octree, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

This question is really simple I think but I can't figure it out.
This code:

```
#include <octomap_msgs/Octomap.h>//Octomap Binary
#include <octomap/OcTree.h>
#include <octomap_msgs/conversions.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "mapper");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  octomap::OcTree* octomap_ = new octomap::OcTree(0.1f);
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

Gives this compile error

```
CMakeFiles/mapper_node.dir/src/nodes/mapper_node.cpp.o: In function `octomath::Pose6D::Pose6D(octomath::Pose6D const&)':
mapper_node.cpp:(.text._ZN8octomath6Pose6DC2ERKS0_[_ZN8octomath6Pose6DC5ERKS0_]+0x3a): undefined reference to `octomath::Quaternion::Quaternion(octomath::Quaternion const&)'
CMakeFiles/mapper_node.dir/src/nodes/mapper_node.cpp.o: In function `octomap::OcTreeNode::updateOccupancyChildren()':
mapper_node.cpp:(.text._ZN7octomap10OcTreeNode23updateOccupancyChildrenEv[_ZN7octomap10OcTreeNode23updateOccupancyChildrenEv]+0x14): undefined reference to `octomap::OcTreeNode::getMaxChildLogOdds() const'
CMakeFiles/mapper_node.dir/src/nodes/mapper_node.cpp.o: In function `octomap::OcTreeBaseImpl<octomap::OcTreeNode, octomap::AbstractOccupancyOcTree>::OcTreeBaseImpl(double)':
mapper_node.cpp:(.text._ZN7octomap14OcTreeBaseImplINS_10OcTreeNodeENS_23AbstractOccupancyOcTreeEEC2Ed[_ZN7octomap14OcTreeBaseImplINS_10OcTreeNodeENS_23AbstractOccupancyOcTreeEEC5Ed]+0x1a): undefined reference to `octomap::AbstractOccupancyOcTree::AbstractOccupancyOcTree()'
```

Isn't this the simplest possible initialization?
What am I missing?

octree 1.6.9, indigo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246411/create-octree/) by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2016-10-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

And it is really silly.

Just add the octomap_ros dependencies to

**CMakeList** :

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS <other dependencies> octomap_ros)
catkin_package(
    CATKIN_DEPENDS <other dependencies> octomap_ros
)
```

and
**package.xml**:

```
 <depend>octomap_ros</depend>
```

---

Originally posted by [kotoko](https://answers.ros.org/users/27417/kotoko/) with karma: 122 on 2016-10-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1